# How do I show an embedded excel file in a WebPage?

Tags: asp.net, html, excel, embed

I want to allow an Excel report to be viewed embedded in a WebPage... is there a way?

- I don't want to use an ActiveX, or OWC (Office Web Components), I just want to open an existing file from the internet explorer application.
- I don't want users to download and then open it.

Using an iframe wouldn't be a problem, but my preliminary tests weren't successful

Any ideas? Is it at all possible?

Comment: Eh?  When you "embed" an XLS in a webpage (i.e., create an iframe targeting the file on the web server) and a chunk of excel shows in the iframe, isn't that an activex control???

Comment: No, not on the web server. It would download and show locally in the internet explorer.

Comment: (I mean, I just want to open a local excel file inside a webpage)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the local person's browser set up and not really anything you can do on your end. If they click a link with the .xls(x) extension, the browser determines if it wants to open it itself or in a new window.

Here 2 microsoft pages on how to change these settings:

[http://support.microsoft.com/.../how-to-configure-internet-explorer-to-open-office-documents-in-the-app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/162059/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-to-open-office-documents-in-the-app)

[http://support.microsoft.com/.../embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773)

Comment: Not really. I've tried to do the same before and had the same problem. Since people can change these settings there is no way to make it consistant. The best you can do is to link it the normal way, but also have a link to instructions to show it embedded to your users if they want to see it.

Answer (score 7):

You should try using the [Excel Web App Embed](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/embed-an-excel-workbook-on-a-web-page-HA102029502.aspx) feature  that lets you embed tables and charts from Excel directly on your Web Page.  You can even let users interact with the spreadsheet so that they can sort and filter data and use your spreadsheets formulas to calculate make their own calculations all without altering the source.

The Excel Web App and storage is all free from Microsoft.  Any data you embed on your Web page can be viewed by all the major destkop and mobile browsers and when you update your spreadsheet the data on your web pages is automatically updated as well.

Comment: I did a search on this today, found this thread, found other solutions. Everything you want to know is here. Excellent solution! http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/embed-an-excel-workbook-on-a-web-page-HA102029502.aspx

Comment: Here is the working link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/embed-an-excel-spreadsheet-on-a-web-page-FX102602477.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is going to be extracting the data out of the Excel file and displaying it in a regular HTML table. Excel isn't exactly safe to invoke from a web page and not everyone has it anyway.

Comment: I need to use Pivot Tables, so this is not an option

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [scribd iPaper Viewer](http://www.scribd.com/tools/ipaper) - this is a Flash based Viewer of XLS (and other) docs.

Answer (score 2):

MOSS 2007 has a nifty feature called [Excel Services](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-3-SharePoint_2007__Excel_Services_-_A_Quick_Introduction.aspx) which might fit the bill...

Answer (score 2):

Excel Web App allows embedding "live" interactive spreadsheets on a web page. For an example, see http://datawiz.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/how-to-embed-excel-on-a-web-page/

Answer (score 0):

in your comments you say that the Excel file is on the client's filesystem, not on the webserver.  i think the security model of sane browsers forbid this; but wouldn't be surprised if setting high permissions to your pages could allow this.

Answer (score -4):

```
<iframe src="file:\\yourpath\yourfile.xls" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: this is not work man !!  add `https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=` before your link

Answer (score -4):

Well this is a bit crude but sort of fits the bill.

1. Select the area of the spreadsheet you wish to display.
2. Copy this area into MS Paint.
3. Select the area in Paint and use the Edit/Copy to/ function to save this as a bitmap.
4. Now load the bitmap as you would any other pic.