# adding excel spreadsheet to webpage

Tags: php, html, excel

I want to add excel spreadsheets to my webpage and prevent global access.

I mean, when only a user logs in can edit the file.but without registration can only view.

Comment: Do you expect us to write it for you? I don't think that would happen... But here's some help: maybe you could use Google Spreadsheets to do the job

Comment: This question is *way* too broad, and the editing part will border the impossible unless you're willing to use Google Spreadsheets

Comment: You can check the similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-show-an-embedded-excel-file-in-a-webpage)

Comment: I`m asking about the importing with privileges.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Drupal, then [Sheetnode](http://drupal.org/project/sheetnode) allows you to edit an Excel workbook within a node/page.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can not *edit* Excel spreadsheets within a browser, there are *Live* versions these days, such as the Google Docs variant, which you could use.

If you just want to provide Excel spreadsheets to download, dependent on a password then you could just supply two different versions of the same file.

A read-only (password protected) version for use by anyone, and if people are logged in, switch this to an unprotected version.

If they have Excel installed and setup in the right way, then it may be the case that the spreadsheet opens within their browser, but more likely it will download and ask to be opened.

Comment: Can it be imported in a webpage and loaded in a browser without needing to install office excel?

Comment: @sikas No, not as a rule.  Excel workbooks are not a supported web format.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Google Spreadsheets, Zoho Spreadsheets or Editgrid can fix this.

Comment: None of this will run on his webpage though, will it?

Comment: I believe at least that EditGrid will do it. I do not have time to research it right now, though.

Comment: I can not entirely tell if EditGrid allows inclusion in one's own website, it certainly provides a spreadsheet facility online, but looks hosted, though it has remote APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the first issue you will have is: "How can a user edit a regular excel file within my website". This is a non-trivial task as there is no easy function to implement that. I would recommend to keep the data on a system that allows users to edit files simultaniosly like Google Docs etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first import imbedded code of excel spreadsheet then use iframe tag in your html code Example below:

```
  <iframe width="402" height="346" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=9A8DF70E172ABC38%21114&authkey=%21AAWX1h4bOSMBGY4&em=2&AllowTyping=True&ActiveCell='EventBudget-Seminar'!A1&wdHideGridlines=True&wdHideHeaders=True&wdDownloadButton=True&wdInConfigurator=True&wdInConfigurator=True&edesNext=false&ejss=false"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).